# Why does Java not compile my code?

Tags: java, eclipse, compiler-errors, compilation

Language: Java
JRE: jre1.8.0_144
IDE: Eclipse Oxygen Release (4.7.0)

Description: After I hit the "run" botton, the code did not compile and red text appear in the console.

Screenshot: [image: Screenshot of the error.]

Here is the code:

```
package chapter3.project2;
import java.util.*;

public class MetricConversion {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("WTF Eclipse?");
    }
}
```

error message:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problem: 
at chapter3.project2.MetricConversion.main(MetricConversion.java:30)
```

It seems that no matter what I put in the main method, the error just kept popping up.

Thank you.

Comment: Clean your project and rebuild. You must have disabled build automatically. Clearly that class doesn't have 30 lines.

Comment: try to remote your `java.util.*` import

Comment: try to do it with javac in cmd. And check if you have anything at line 30 in your MetricConversion.java

Comment: @Abe did not work :-(

Comment: @SergeiSirik I DONT EVEN HAVE A LINE 30 OH GOD PLEASE HELP ME

Comment: man, try to create a new project. This is completely strange!! SOS

Comment: What about `javac MetricConversion.java` in terminal? But anyway seems like Eclipse misbehaving, did you try to simply restart it? Clean *.class files from target directory?

Comment: I didn't disable it. Still not working... Screen shot: https://imgur.com/LIPp5VV

Comment: Have you tried cleaning and rebuilding your project (maybe after restarting your IDE or even computer)?

Comment: @SergeiSirik    javac: ?????: MetricConversion.java  
??: javac <options> <source files>  
-help ?????????

Comment: [javac](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/tools/windows/javac.html)

Comment: I created a new Java Project and it somehow worked. I will definitely get a new IDE after a pass this class. Thanks guys... Don't know how to @ several users.

Comment: Did you even install the JDK? If so, did you make sure the IDE knows where it is?

Answer (score 0):

Where is jre library? Why not compile and run from source folder? 
Check project property and add jre runtime library also create source folder (src) and compile and run.
Or
Build a clean Java project and add packages and classes in src folder.